# Display menu in two categories

Tags: php, mysql

i have one table as `item` which has menu items as `item_name` and each `item_name` has corresponding column `cat_id` which states that `cat_id=0` is Veg item and if `cat_id=1` then it is Non veg

```
    <ul class="tabs">
    <?php foreach($data as $menu){ 
         if($menu['cat_id']==0){    ?>
                             <li>Veg Menu</li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <li>Non-Veg Menu</li>
        <?php }  }?>
            <li>tab3</li>
            <li>tab4</li>
             <li>tab5</li>
        </ul>
```

Problem is that m getting `veg menu` tab as many times as `item_names` and not getting not veg tab.

Ps. I included Veg and Non veg in loop as i am not getting any other way of displaying it . Question is silly but pl do not down vote as m stuck :|

Comment: That you get either of those as many times as you have items is only natural, because you are outputting one of these in _every_ loop iteration. And if you get veg only, and no non-veg – well that most likely means `$menu['cat_id']` _is_ 0 (or anything that is equal 0 by PHP’s lose comparison rules) for each item. So what have you done so far to _debug_ this …?

Comment: If you do `print_r($data)` and paste the contents of that here, we'll be able to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Hi @SharkofMirkwood              `Array ( [0] => Array ( [cat_id] => 0 [menu_id] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [cat_id] => 0 [menu_id] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [cat_id] => 0 [menu_id] => 1) [3] => Array ( [cat_id] => 0 [menu_id] => 3) )`

Comment: Well there's your problem - `cat_id` is indeed always 0! How are you fetching this data? I guess something must be going wrong there. Maybe you can post some more of your code.

Comment: it is `SELECT t1.cat_id,t2.me_id,group_concat(concat(t1.it_na,'-',t1.it_pr,'-',t1.cat_id)) as ite FROM ittr t1 LEFT JOIN meyt t2 ON t1.me_id = t2.me_id WHERE t2.resyf_id = 8767
group by t2.me_na`